# Differential equation math problem (Newton's Law of Cooling)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> The rate at which an object's temperature T is changing at any time is roughly proportional to the difference between its temperature and the temperature of the surrounding medium $T_m$. Thus we have $\frac{dT}{dt} = -k(T-T_m)$, where $k$ is a constant. Suppose initial temperature of the object is $T_0$

Using separation of variables, $T-T_m = Ae^{-kt}$ where, A is an arbitrary constant.

Since At $t=0$, $T_0 - T_m = A$, $T=T_m + (T_0 - T_m)e^{-kt}$

> Now, use a change of variable, convert the equation to the form of $y=y_0 e^{-kt}$, and show that $t=\ln 2 /2$

I let $y= T-T_m$ and $y_0 = T_0 - T_m$

Then, $\ln y = \ln y_0 e^{-kt}$

I cant seem to prove that $t= \ln 2/2$

Comment: Within the body of your question, $t$ as described in the second part is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Your working upto here is okay

$$ T=T_m + (T_0 - T_m)e^{-kt} $$

Or

$$ \frac{T-T_m}{T_0 - T_m}=e^{-kt}$$

which is in the form

$$ y = y_0 ~ e^{-kt}$$

But the way the question is given we cannot prove that $t= \ln 2/2.$